# asynctask for android connecting to mysql using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Can anyone help me put how to make this in asynctask http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/. This is not working on android 4.0.3. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: guys i already fix this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strict mode. But this mode is just for testing and forcing android to ignore "Running on main thread". It is highly recommended to use `AsyncTak`.

You have noticed that tutorial used `AsyncTask` in some parts as well but it runs on UI thread. This is not good. You have to delete that part:

For example in the tutorial we have:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
```

You have to change it to:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    public void run() {
```

I'm sure this will help you.